# How Can I Access Github Wiki Pages Under The Github-Pages

Tags: git, shell, github, github-pages, wiki

I have this Github-Pages (GH-Pages) [based website](https://atErik.github.io/Transpiler.and.similar.List/).
I will call the above website as project TASL "GH-Pages" or "GHP".
Current config is such, that, the "main" branch of TASL project github site is shown as "GHP".

I also have [Github Wiki pages](https://github.com/atErik/Transpiler.and.similar.List/wiki) for same/above TASL project. I will call it here "GHW" = Github Wiki Pages.

TASL project site, aka, main project's github site, is [here](https://github.com/atErik/Transpiler.and.similar.List/).
I will call it here "GHPDS" = Github Project Development Site.

Is it possible to access TASL project's wiki pages (GHW), UNDER the github-pages (GHP) site?
How can I bring all wiki pages (GHW) accessible like this under GHP:
`https://atErik.github.io/Transpiler.and.similar.List/ghw/`
or
`https://atErik.github.io/Transpiler.and.similar.List/wiki/`?

Does github has a builtin process that can be tapped to achieve this?

Can a script be used in TASL project developer-member's computer to replicate the GHW pages under a ("ghw" or "wiki") sub-directory in the main project's github site (GHPDS), in order to bring it under the GHP (when any GHW page is edited/updated)?
(such/this script need to: monitor GHW pages/site , trigger when any file/page is edited/updated under the GHW site , download & copy it , fix/adjust URLs , add specific header & footer message , paste into "ghw"/"wiki" sub-directory of main project TASL site , upload into GHPDS (main project TASL site), etc, etc).
and I want to show a specific message/notice in header+footer area, like below:
*"For editing/updating this page, goto project's Wiki pages [here](https://github.com/atErik/Transpiler.and.similar.List/wiki)."*

Above are copying GHW (github wiki pages) content from: GHW site --> GHPDS "ghw" sub-folder.

It would also be okay, if a solution/answer can do this way:
  GHW site <-- GHPDS("gh-wiki") --> GHPDS("ghw").
for-example, a sub-directory `"gh-wiki"` will hold the actual source code pages for GHW github wiki pages, and will also hold the source code pages for the second-sub-folder `"ghw"` .
All users/contributors will have to edit here first: `github.com/gh-username/proj-name/gh-wiki/`
then a script in developer's computer will have to make two copies of all pages under the `"gh-wiki"` sub-folder :
one copy of page will go into (GHW) github wiki pages (after URLs are adjusted by the script) here: `github.com/gh-username/proj-name/wiki/`,
and another copy of page will goto `"ghw"` sub-folder (after URLs are adjusted by the script) here: `github.com/gh-username/proj-name/ghw/` .
and to keep the `github.com/gh-username/proj-name/gh-wiki/` sub-folder contents out of GHP access, we will add this `"exclude: gh-wiki/"` as a new-config line inside the `"_config.yml"` file, this cfg is used by GHP site's Jekyll engine to apply specific configuration(s), to produce/show specific changes.
So my objective is also possible in above way, that is, same wiki pages (GHW) are available/accessible under the github-pages (GHP) site from here:
`gh-username.github.io/proj-name/ghw/`
and also accessible via (GHW) github wiki pages here:
`github.com/gh-username/proj-name/wiki/`
in above GHW site we just have to show a message to all users/devs, that, wiki is purposefully kept as read-only, and for edit user/dev need to goto specific GHDPS sub-folder pages, here:
`github.com/gh-username/proj-name/gh-wiki/`

Answer (score 0):

One way of bringing the GHW (github wiki site/pages) under the GHP ("github-pages"), is to create a `"ghw"` or `"wiki"` sub-directory / sub-folder, under the main project TASL, here:
https://github.com/atErik/Transpiler.and.similar.List/ghw/
then add a new `"README.md"` file there.
then manually copy content of GHW `"Home"` page, & paste into the `"README.md"` file, Save changes.
then GHW site content can+will appear under GHP site, in below url location:
https://atErik.github.io/Transpiler.and.similar.List/ghw/

I have done this, in other project, so I know, this works.
but it is a manual process, not an automated solution.

If there are many GHW pages, & different users are editing/updating different ones at different time, then it would not be comfortable to continuously keep on copy-paste new/updated content/changes from GHW site into `"ghw"` sub-directory of project site.

So I want to avoid doing this after every edit done in the GHW site.